# Is there a GetModuleThreadId function?

Tags: c++, c

Problem: Windows platform.

dll_1  in a process needs to know the thread id 
of dll_2 in the same process.

dll_1 already has the hmodule of dll_2.

Although it may seem a trivial task there is no 
documentation at all on how this can achieved.

You would think there would be a function such
as `GetRemoteModuleThreadId()` but if there is then it has been
concealed for security reasons.

Comment: There is no such thing as "thread of DLL". There are threads within process, there are modules/DLLs within process. Threads and modules have no specific relation between them.

Comment: A DLL does not have its own thread, and a DLL's functions can be used by multiple threads in the same process.  So such a function makes no sense. What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

A thread and a DLL are distinct and unrelated concepts. A DLL is just "some code that has been loaded into the process's memory" and a thread is a distinct sequence of code execution that happens to execute code, whether it's in the main exe or a DLL.

Comment: I am trying to suspend a dll from executing its code so that I can gather information on its data and then resume it.

Comment: ok so you need to suspend whichever thread is altering the data. This thread does not belong to the DLL, it belongs to the process (the concept of a separate execution context that cannot pollute other processes or be polluted by them)

Comment: Richard that's is the point, how to obtain the thread id ?
I can use the tool32help functions but they enumerate the running threads within the process without any extra information that would tie the threads to the tasks run by the dll.

Comment: @khalfan Precisely. There's no information besides that, since there's no such thing as "tasks run by the dll"

Comment: Hmm. I will just go through this 'Multithreading Applications in Win32: The Complete Guide to Threads By Jim 
Beveridge, Robert Wiener.'

Comment: one thing you can do is run the program in a debugger and set a breakpoint on the lines what will alter data. Any thread that is about to execute those lines will then freeze the process

Comment: exported functions of a dll called by a thread are part of of the thread but dllMain has its own thread.